# Global vs. Local in JavaScript example

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to learn the basics of JavaScript and ran into something I'm not totally 100% about. Here is the code without declaring the my_number variable inside the function:

```js
var my_number = 7; // this has global scope

var timesTwo = function(number) {
    my_number = number * 2;
    console.log("Inside the function my_number is: ");
    console.log(my_number);
}; 

timesTwo(6);

console.log("Outside the function my_number is: ")
console.log(my_number);
```

This outputs to:
Inside the function my_number is: 12
Outside the function my_number is: 12

First, from what I've read if you don't declare your variable inside a function it will take on the value of a global variable of the same name. My guess as to what's happening here is that when the function call passes the number `6` it passed it to the function, does the multiplication and logs the result (12) to the console. Once the function has ended it keeps that value `12` (essentially overwrites the global value?) and logs the number `12` again to the console.

One the other hand, when I declare the variable inside the function, var `my_number = number * 2;` it work just like I expect it to and prints out `12` Inside the function and uses the global variable `7` for the last line of code.

```js
   var my_number = 7; // this has global scope

    var timesTwo = function(number) {
        var my_number = number * 2;
        console.log("Inside the function my_number is: ");
        console.log(my_number);
    }; 

    timesTwo(6);

    console.log("Outside the function my_number is: ")
    console.log(my_number);
```

Inside the function my_number is: 12

Outside the function my_number is: 7

Am I understanding this correctly or not? **Especially** the first snippet of code. I'd like to fully grasp this concept before moving on, it seems important to me.

Comment: Your understanding is correct. And both code snippets are working the way they are coded.

Comment: *"if you don't declare your variable inside a function it will take on the value of a global variable of the same name."* Not exactly. The variable inside the function **is** the global variable (it doesn't just have the same value).

Comment: Thank you both for your replies! I do appreciate it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your understanding seems to be fine, though I'm not sure of the following statement:

> Once the function has ended it keeps that value `12` (essentially overwrites the global value?)

This does have nothing to do with the function ending. As there was no local variable with that name in the function, every occurence of `my_number` referred directly to the global variable, which was written to in the assignment and read from in the logging statement. The `timesTwo` functin doesn't have its own copy of the variable.

Comment: @Cosmo Cosmo  You may also be interested in this article, which through explaining how the delete function works also gives greater understanding of variable scope. http://perfectionkills.com/understanding-delete/

Comment: Ok, I think I'm getting it. This really does clears up alot things for me! Thanks!